# How can blockchain be applied other than cryptocurrencies?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, nft

How can blockchain be applied other than cryptocurrencies? May I ask for some diagrams that abstractly explain the system behind the non-monetary application of blockchain? I cannot seem to wrap my head around the idea of it being applied on other things such as smart contracts, NFT, etc.

I tried searching on the internet but many of the explanation are either too simple or complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly people understand blockchain only be used in cryptocurrencies. But In real world there are lot other spaces blockchain can be useful.

For example :

1. Financial Solutions
2. Real state
3. Health care
4. Games
5. Entertainment

You name the domain and you shall find the problem can be solved by blockchain.

But as beginner we really don't know what kind of smart contracts / dapps we can write to learn more about blockchain. So here are some ideas I'm trying to apply in my blockchain developer journey. (prerequisites : knowledge of **Solidity** and **Javascript**). If you don't have that first step to grab this information and then try to write these small but effective smart contracts.

1. Write smart contract to check balance.
2. Write smart contract to transfer balance from one address/account to another. (Make sure you implement security around only authorized user can send money) try require
3. Smart Contract to store and retrieve data on the Ethereum blockchain.(can follow this tutorial https://livecodestream.dev/post/interacting-with-smart-contracts-from-web-apps/)

Once you are comfortable with writing smart contract then you can link your smart contract with front end (where end user interact) with Web3.js library (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/) to complete your dapp.

You can use testnet to deploy your dapps because to deploy your daap on mainnet we need pay the gas (fees).

But as a starter we should try all these in local.

So to start your programming in blockchain you can use 'Remix IDE'. Best part of this IDE is that no setup required in order to start your development. Simply go to this [link](https://remix.ethereum.org/) and start you coding.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a program that no one owns... it has no administrator.  The program is immutable... no one owns it, no one can change it.  It doesn't run on a corporate cloud... it runs on a peer-to-peer network.  Anyone can join the peer-to-peer network from anywhere.  All this is what decentralization means.  There is no single point of failure.

The program is open source, so that people can verify its logic.  If people agree that the logic is fair, they use the program.  This is what trustless means: the logic can be verified and there is no party to trust.

This is what a smart contract is and what Ethereum has started making possible.

Try to take a look at how much you trust things, rather than being able to verify that it is true.

For example, your question has received some upvotes.  Are those real and accurate?  Are you sure that an administrator has not tampered with it?  Whenever you see any poll online, realize how much trust you are putting that it is not manipulated.

When you see a price online, how do you know it is fair?  Can you see how it computes prices?  What if you could see that code and analyze and discuss it with others?  That's what you get from a decentralized exchange like uniswap.org.

You play a game like poker online.  How do you know it is fair?  That the dealt cards are fair?  How do you know that you are not playing against an administrator or their friend who can see your cards?

These are some examples.  I have started with online examples because they are easier to understand.  Generally, think of how much depends on databases.  All databases have administrators who can change whatever they want on the database.  Smart contracts are open databases, where everyone knows the rules on how they can be updated.  If there is an unfair smart contract, no one will use it.

An open database may worry you.  But encryption, combined with [zero-knowledge proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof), will allow you to use smart contract applications as privately as you want.